# Obtener el ID correspondiente al Aceptar

Tags: php

Agradezco a quien me pueda orientar.

Tengo tres páginas:

La primera página de Consulta es para que el usuario señale el mes y el año del servicio que realizo y de la cual debe realizar una aprobación.

La segunda página es la respuesta en la que efectivamente se muestran los servicios que se prestaron efectivamente en el mes y año mencionado en la anterior página. Está página contiene la opción de aceptar el servicio o borrarlo.

La tercera  página se presenta cuando se carga la aceptación enlazado a un "ID".

El problema se presenta cuando acepta, pues el ID relacionado corresponde al último resultado obtenido por la variable en un ciclo WHILE la cual no corresponde al necesitado.

Quedo muy atento.

Gracias

CÓDIGO

---

```
$reporte = mysqli_query ($mysqli, "SELECT DISTINCT id,                 Nombre_Cliente, SUM(Horas_Facturar) as SUMAH, SUM(Costo_Hora) as SUMAV FROM   Maestro WHERE Nombre_Consultor = '$nombre_consult' AND  Estado_Cta_Cobro !=   '$estado_cta_cobro' AND Estado_Reporte = '$estado_rep' AND   YEAR(Fecha_Servicio) = '$ano_servicio' AND MONTH(Fecha_Servicio) =   '$mes_servicio' GROUP BY Nombre_Cliente");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reporte))
{   
$fila = $row["id"];
$nombre_cliente = $row["Nombre_Cliente"];
$horas_facturar = $row["SUMAH"];
$costo_hora = $row["SUMAV"];


echo ("<Table width= '100%' border = '0' cellspacing = '0' cellpadding=  '0'>\n");
echo ("<tr>\n");
echo ("<td width= '15%'><a href=Aceptar_Cta_Cobro.php? id=$fila>   Aceptar sesión</a></td>\n");
echo ("<td width= '15%'><a href=Borrar_Cta_Cobro.php? id=$fila> Borrar   sesión</a></td>\n");
echo "Fila: $fila";
echo ("<td width='50%'>$nombre_cliente</a></td>\n");
echo ("<td width='10%'>$horas_facturar</a></td>\n");
echo ("<td width='10%'>$costo_hora</a></td>\n");
echo ("</tr>\n");
echo ("</table>\n");
echo "<hr size= 2 color = ffffff width = 100% align= left>";
$_SESSION['fila'] = $fila;
}
```

Comment: buenos días: Me parece muy lógico lo que dices, pero
Cómo puedo entonces dejarlo funcionando. Ya saque la SESSION fuera de los corchetes “{}” pero nada. Siempre me
Muestra el último dato obtenido del ciclo WHILE?

Answer (score -1):

```
...
$_SESSION['fila'] = $fila;
```

Estas sobreescribiendo la sesion.
Al final del ciclo el valor de SESSION es el del ultimo ciclo.

Comment: Si te fijas, en realidad, si bien en cierto lo que indicas, la session no actua dentro del problema que tiene @Julián, ya que el id de la ficha, la esta asignado antes. Y esta mostrando ese parametro no el valor de dla session

Comment: Si me fije...hum! pues que pruebe iterar como mismo hace pero en vez de dar la salida con `echo` que lo concatene en una variable `$output` y luego le de salida a esa variable
`$ouput = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reporte))
{
    $output .= "<a href = '$row[id]'>Accion</a>"
}

echo $output;`